# Icons in the template are not displayed - Bootstrap 4, Django (after adding amazon s3)

Tags: django, amazon-s3, bootstrap-4

After adding all static files to amazon S3 my icons are not displayed (as in the picture below). I use the purchased Frond Endu Bootstrap4 and personally i did not add changes inside static files.

Why my django application does not  display icons? Any help will be appreciated.
[image]

**settings.py**

```
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
```

**F12 Consol**

[image]

Comment: Can you check the browser's dev tools network tab (`F12` --> Network, reload). You'll probably have 404 Errors there. Perhaps you need to adapt `STATIC_URL` in the settings.

Comment: I added a view from my console to the topic above

Comment: See S3 docs to set CORS headers on your bucket: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#how-do-i-enable-cors. For some background on why you're seeing this error, see [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).